# Can Java Swing HTML parser parse any type of Markup Language contained in an HTML document or just HTML?

Tags: java, html, xml, swing, parsing

I have an HTML with some XML data in it,and I want it to be parsed.Will the Swing HTML parser be able to navigate within those XML tags?

Comment: What happened when you tried it?

Comment: +1 for acknowledging both the 'literal' & 'thinking outside the box' answers.  :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your looking for an HTML Parser which processes HTML simular to modern browsers then you should look at JSoup http://www.jsoup.org

Comment: Correct for advising me for what to use

Answer (score 3):

> Will the Swing HTML parser be able to navigate within those XML tags?

Not while the `JEditorPane` uses the default `HTMLEditorKit`.  That does not even support all the HTML elements, *..from HTML 3.2!*

Comment: Up for a straight forward answer